# How to build a parameterised query with IN sql keyword?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

That's what I tried & failed:

```
      string sql = "... WHERE [personID] IN (@sqlIn) ...";
      string sqlIn = "1,2,3,4,5";
      SqlCeCommand cmd.Parameters.Add("@sqlIn", SqlDbType.NText).Value = sqlIn;

      SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
      da.Fill(ds); // > Error
```

Error details:

> The ntext and image data types cannot be used in WHERE, HAVING, GROUP BY, ON, or IN clauses, except when these data types are used with the LIKE or IS NULL predicates.

Can't I pass all the IDs as one parameter? Should I add one by one all IDs?

P.S: Notice SqlCE

Comment: cleanup up your example also what is the value of sqlIn

Comment: The code is actually comparing personID to the entire string of "1,2,3,4,5", not against each item separated by commas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't parameterise that as a single parameter. Your query is doing an "in" on a **single** value, so is essentially:

```
... Where personId = '1,2,3,4,5'
```

(give or take a parameter). This is *usually* also an invalid or sub-optimal equality test, and certainly isn't what you were trying to query.

Options;

- use raw concatenation: often involves a SQL injection risk, and allows poor query plan re-use
- on full SQL server: use a UDF to split a single param
- on full SQL server, use a TVP
- add parameters dynamically, and add the various @param3 etc to the TSQL

The last is the most reliable, and "dapper-dot-net" has a feature built in to do this for you (since it is commonly needed):

```
int[] ids = ...
var rows = conn.Query<SomeType>(
    @"... Where Id in @ids",
    new { ids }).ToList();
```

This, when run via dapper-dot-net, will add a parameter per item in "ids", giving it the right value etc, and fixing the SQL so it executes, for example:

```
"... Where Id in (@ids0, @ids1, @ids2)"
```

(if there were 3 items in "ids")

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to split the sqlIn string by comma, convert each to an integer, and build the IN statement manually.

```
  string sqlIn = "1,2,3,4,5";
  string inParams = sqlIn.Split(',');
  List<string> paramNames = new List<string>();
  for(var i = 0; i < inParams.Length; ++i){
        string paramName = "@param" + i.ToString();
        SqlCeCommand cmd.Parameters.Add(paramName, SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(inParams[i]);
        paramNames.Add(paramName);
  }

  string sql = "... WHERE [personID] IN (" +
      string.Join(",", paramNames) +
      ") ...";
```

Comment: I just noticed Marc's answer. His suggestion is better. There are ORMs that make this problem a non-issue. SubSonic, EF, nHibernate, Dapper, etc.

Comment: I'll use this simpler version